# How to import part of a file name to a field

Tags: vba, import, ms-access-2007, filenames

I have a file that i import into access 2007 and i was wondering if i can take part of that file name and put it into a field in access? For example here is one example of a file name:

"20140211_agent_statistics.csv"

I have done some research on this but cant seem to find the answer when numbers change all of the time. I just need to grab the numbers on this file name. However, these numbers change all of the time. Does anyone have a solution for this? Thank you in advance. Any help and code is much appreciated i am very new to vba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working on a few assumptions:

You are importing this by code so it picks up the file name?
The numbers are the date so probably always 8 characters long?

If you import by code you will assign the file name to a variable, in case you don't here is how to:

```
Dim strFileO as String, strFileLoc as String
strFileLoc = "C:\YourFolder\" ' Folder where file is saved
strFileO = Dir(strFileLoc & "*.csv")
```

Above will pick up any .csv file in the folder, you should move them once imported

Once you have the strFileo then to get the date:

```
Dim lDate as Long
lDate = Left(strFileO,8)
'Or if the numbers aren't always 8 characters:
lDate = Left(strFileO. InStr(strFileO,"_") - 1) ' Assumes numbers followed by "_"
```